# Concatenate an existing define with a postfix to get a define in C

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I have 2 defines:

```
#define REG1 (BASE_ADDR + REG1_OFFSET) //address
#define REG1_MASK 0x3f
```

I want to generate a command through macro that would use both defines but with giving as a variable only REG1. for instance, writing down

```
WRITE_TO_REG(REG1)
```

will result in:

```
foo(REG1,0xa5a5a5a5,REG1_MASK)
```

For this I created these macros:

```
#define MASK_REG(REG) REG ## _MASK
#define FOO_REG(REG) foo(REG,0xa5a5a5a5,MASK_REG(REG))
```

but I get an error (I'm compiling in gcc): pasting ")" and "_MASK" does not give a valid preprocessing token.

I tried a few variations, including:

```
#define MASK_REG(REG) MASK2_REG(REG)
#define MASK2_REG(REG) IDENTITY(REG) ## _MASK
#define IDENTITY(REG) REG
```

or:

```
#define PASTE2(x,y) PASTE(x,y)
#define PASTE(x,y) x ## y
#define MASK_REG(REG) PASTE2(REG,_MASK)
```

None of them worked. any ideas?

Adding a complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define REG1_BASE_ADDR 0x100
#define REG1_OFFSET 0x5
#define REG1 (REG1_BASE_ADDR + REG1_OFFSET) 
#define REG1_MASK 0x3f
#define PASTE2(x,y) PASTE(x,y)
#define PASTE(x,y) x ## y
#define MASK_REG(REG) REG ## _MASK
#define FOO_REG(REG) (REG + MASK_REG(REG))

int main() {
  printf("addr: %x, mask: %x, addr+mask: %x",REG1,REG1_MASK,FOO_REG(REG1));
}
```

Comment: Try removing the spaces around `##`

Comment: How do you invoke the macro functions? The definitions itself shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: For instance:  FOO_REG(REG1)

Comment: The problem seems to me is that REG1 is evaluated to (BASE_ADDR + REG1_OFFSET) before the pre-processor tries to paste the macros.

Comment: Yes, `REG1` isn't expanded here, but I can't reproduce the error message. Please provide a short complete source file reproducing the error.

Comment: There, I added a complete code block.

Comment: Better use inline function for this issue

Comment: OT: `%h` isn't a conversion specifier, you need `%hd`, or simply `%d` (the `h` and `hh` length modifiers are rather useless, execpt for `n` conversions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I actually think I got it.

The problem was that the macro REG1 was evaluated BEFORE pre-processsor made the paste to _MASK.
It seems I didn't need any more defines to perform the paste:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REG1_BASE_ADDR 0x100
#define REG1_OFFSET 0x5
#define REG1 (REG1_BASE_ADDR + REG1_OFFSET) 
#define REG1_MASK 0x3f

#define FOO_REG(REG) (REG + REG##_MASK)

int main() {
  printf("addr: %x, mask: %x, addr+mask: %x",REG1,REG1_MASK,FOO_REG(REG1));
}
```